# What alternative notation of subscripts/superscripts that are also treated as SYMBOLS in Mathematica?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I tried to avoid using the subscript $A_0$ in the Module, and get an error with $A[0]$.

```
    In[119]:= Module[{A[0] = 1},A[0]]

         During evaluation of In[119]:= Module::lvset: Local variable specification {A[0]=1} contains A[0]=1, which is an assignment to A[0]; only assignments to symbols are allowed. >>

      Out[119]= Module[{A[0] = 1}, A[0]]
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, I tried to define "A0, A1, A2", but failed with command

```
         Sum[Ai, {i, 3}]
```

I just want a Symbol of combining a letter with a postfix of number, e.g. Ai, A_i, A[i], A(i),... any notation that is treated as a Symbol in MMa would be okay.

EDIT2:

For example,

```
    In[130]:= Module[{A0 = 1},Sum[Symbol["A" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, 3}]]

     Out[130]= A0 + A1 + A2 + A3
```

But I wish to replace $A0$ with $1$, and get `1+ A1 + A2 + A3`

This would work when A0 defined globally.

```
     In[132]:= Sum[Symbol["A" <> ToString[i]], {i, A0 = 1; 0, 3}]

     Out[132]= 1 + A1 + A2 + A3
```

Comment: What about using the [Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html), in particular, [Symbolize](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/ref/Symbolize.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Honestly I would suggest to not create symbols with `Symbol` or `ToExpression` for that use case. You can very well use `Downvalues` as you tried in the first place also for local variables, you just can't make those definitions within the local symbols list, e.g. this will work:

```
Module[{A},A[0] = 1; Sum[A[i],{i,0,3}]]
```

As explained in answers to other questions (e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/169)) localication with `Module` will actually create a "new" symbol (something like `A$573`) which will in this case leak from the `Module` (this is called lexical scoping, at least in Mathematica speak. It can be argued whether what `Module` does actually qualifies for what that term is used in general). These leaking symbols can be used as a feature, but I doubt it is what you want in this case.

The following might be closer to what you actually had in mind, although it also can have subtleties when used in more complicated circumstances (see again e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/169) for more details and links):

```
Block[{A}, A[0] = 1; Sum[A[i],{i,0,3}]]
```

There is also `Array` which I think should be mentioned in that context:

```
Module[{A}, A[0] = 1; Total@Array[A, 4, 0]]
```

Comment: With `In[207]:= Module[{A}, A[0] = 1; Sum[A[i], {i, 0, 3}]]`, I got this `

Out[207]= 1 + A\$2471[1] + A\$2471[2] + A\$2471[3]`. Is this normal? How to remove "\$2471" here?

Comment: @OsirisXu: yes, that is the expected behaviour. As I mentioned, typically the `Block` construct seems more appropriate in this context, but it all depends. What you see with `Module` is the local variables leaking. You'll find quite some answers on this site where this is explained and where this is used as a feature (search for Module,scoping,local variables).

Comment: Nice. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to assemble symbols as strings and use `Symbol`:

```
Sum[
  Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]],
  {i, 5}
]
```

> ```
> x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5
> ```

For use in `Module` you will need to inject this symbol, e.g. using `With`:

```
With[{sym = Symbol["x" <> ToString[3]]},
  Module[{sym = 7}, sym + 3]
]
```

> ```
> 10
> ```

Also be aware of `Unique` and its function:

```
Unique["x"]
```

> ```
> x6
> ```

---

Judging from your second example `Module` may be the wrong tool for the job.  Consider:

```
Block[{A0 = 1}, Sum[Symbol["A" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, 3}]]

Sum[Symbol["A" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, 3}] /. A0 -> 1

Sum[a[i], {i, 0, 3}] /. a[0] -> 1
```

> ```
> 1 + A1 + A2 + A3
>
> 1 + A1 + A2 + A3
>
> 1 + a[1] + a[2] + a[3]
> ```

Comment: This is nice. But this notation is not that convenient to use. Any other alternatives? I just want a Symbol of combining a letter with a postfix of number, e.g. Ai, A_i, A[i], A(i),... any notation that is treated as a Symbol in MMa would be okay.

Comment: @OsirisXu could you give an example application for this?  That will help me determine methods that may be applicable.

Comment: For example, `In[130]:= Module[{A0 = 1},Sum[Symbol["A" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, 3}]]

Out[130]= A0 + A1 + A2 + A3`

But I wish to replace $A0$ with $1$, and get `1+ A1 + A2 + A3`

Comment: @OsirisXu I need more context than that.  What operation or procedure are you doing?  For that example would `Sum[A[i], {i, 0, 3}] /. A[0] -> 1` be acceptable?

Comment: In other words, @Osiris, **what are you really trying to do**?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, that does the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @OsirisXu okay, I added it to my answer.  Notice the form with `Block` as well, but make sure you understand what `Block` does before you start using it.  Generally I think you'll have better luck with `Replace` or `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) for what I believe you're doing.