# Table of Variables

Tags: variable-definitions, list-manipulation

I use a list of variables `{x1, x2, x3}` to `Solve` a particular set of equations.

I am now trying to generalise this depending on the number of equations.

I need something along the lines of `Table[{"x" i}, {i,1,Length[equations]}]` which prints `{x1, x2, x3, x4,...}` etc.

However, `"x" i` obviously does not work. Nor does `x[[i]]` as `{x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]]}` won't work in `Solve`.

Any quick thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Closely related, perhaps duplicate?: [(6623)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6623/121), [(20160)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20160/121)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `Symbol` to convert a string into a symbol...

```
Table[Symbol["$x" <> ToString@i], {i, 5}]
```

> `{$x1, $x2, $x3, $x4, $x5}`

One word of caution. I tend to keep programmatically generated variables prepended with a `$` to avoid any collisions with any other variables I might've defined. Just from experience.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: [`Unique`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unique.html) can also be helpful.

Comment: I admit I also use leading `$` for variable names but I think it is important to reminde people that this has the danger to conflict with `Module` local variable names, especially when they end -- as in this case -- with digits...

Comment: Is it possible to use this within a `Control` environment, in a `Manipulate`? I tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. Somehow `Control[{{a1, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]` is not the same as `Control[{{Symbol["$a" <> ToString@1], 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]`. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 19):

You almost have found a simple solution: try `x[i]` instead of `x[[i]]`

```
Solve[{x[1] + x[2] == 2, x[1] - x[2] == 1}, {x[1], x[2]}]
```

> {{x[1] -> 3/2, x[2] -> 1/2}}

List of this variables:

```
Array[x,2]
```

> {x[1], x[2]}

Comment: So close :P Thanks!

Comment: I actually think that this is in a lot of cases the better solution: it is much easier to access these variables in a programmatic way and many functions as `Solve`, `NDSolve`,... do accept "nonatomic" variable names, so at least for them it isn't necessary to create those symbols programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

Or you could make a function to add a range of numbers to a predefined string("x")

```
f2 := Function[{i}, ToExpression["x" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[i]]

f2[5]
```

> {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}

Or a function to add a range of numbers to any string

```
f3 := Function[{i, s}, ToExpression[s <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[i]]

f3[5, "y"]
```

> {y1,y2,y3,y4,y5}