# Assiging random values to an array of variables

Tags: variable

I want to create a number of variables and assign random values to them. This is possible in Python using a single line of command.

To be more specific say I want to create 10 variables whose value will be $[0.1,1]$ randomly. Instead of declaring every variable individually and then assigning values to them, is there any easier way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: `Evaluate @ Array[x, 10] = RandomReal[1, 10]` doesn't float your boat?

Comment: @J. M. No, but it bloat my goat

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36886/table-of-variables

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Does it explain goat bloating?

Comment: @bel No, gloat loathing.

Comment: Why make such an insignificant edit?  `....RandomReal[{0.1, 1}, 10]` -- this hardly matters, but it makes `RandomReal[1, 10]` seem slightly wrong.

Comment: I have found that my variable cant be $0$. @MichaelE2

Comment: @Marco, you are right; I forgot it was `HoldFirst`. Thanks. :)

Comment: Wonders why it is necessary that these random values be assigned to individual variables and not concatenated in a list?

Comment: @image_doctor Now *that* is a good question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit

Here is a *Mathematica* one-liner, courtesy of ciao, that does what you ask for:

```
SeedRandom[42];
Array[(x[#] = RandomReal[1]) &, 10];

Definition @ x
```

> ```
> x[1] = 0.425905
> x[2] = 0.391023
> x[3] = 0.347069
> x[4] = 0.453741
> x[5] = 0.555963
> x[6] = 0.289169
> x[7] = 0.296848
> x[8] = 0.206408
> x[9] = 0.32517
> x[10] = 0.973325
> ```

And here is another one, producing non-indexed variables.

```
SeedRandom[42];
MapThread[Set, {Symbol["x" <> #] & /@ IntegerString[Range[10]], RandomReal[1, 10]}];

List @@ OwnValues /@ Hold[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10]
```

> ```
> {{HoldPattern[x1] :> 0.425905}, {HoldPattern[x2] :> 0.391023}, 
>  {HoldPattern[x3] :> 0.347069}, {HoldPattern[x4] :> 0.453741}, 
>  {HoldPattern[x5] :> 0.555963}, {HoldPattern[x6] :> 0.289169}, 
>  {HoldPattern[x7] :> 0.296848}, {HoldPattern[x8] :> 0.206408}, 
>  {HoldPattern[x9] :> 0.32517}, {HoldPattern[x10] :> 0.973325}}
> ```

Comment: Why not just `Array[(x[#] = RandomReal[1]) &, 10]` for the first?

Comment: @ciao. Because I didn't think of that.

Comment: @m_goldberg,   thanks for such elaborated answer.