# Matrix of functions

Tags: differential-equations, functions, symbolic, symbols

I want to create a matrix of functions. As explained in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36886/table-of-variables), I can create a matrix of variables:

```
labels = {"A", "B", "C"};
M = Table[Symbol["f" <> i <> j], {i, labels}, {j, labels}];
M // MatrixForm
```

[image]

But I want to create a matrix with functions `fAA[t]` etc. The motivation is that I am generating a matrix of differential equations that I will solve with `DSolve`. I tried the following simple modification but it does **not** work

```
M = Table[Symbol["f" <> i <> j <> "[t]"], {i, labels}, {j, labels}];
```

Comment: `Table[Symbol["f" <> i <> j][t], {i, labels}, {j, labels}]` ?

Comment: Oh yeah. I think that does the job. Will post if there are any issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Recommend that you consider using an indexed variable.

```
labels = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

If `f[x, y]` is distinct from `f[y, x]`

```
ClearAll[f]

Format[f[x_, y_]] := Subscript[f, ToString[x] <> ToString[y]]

(m = Outer[f[##][t] &, labels, labels]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

If `f[x, y]` is equal to `f[y, x]`

```
ClearAll[f]

Format[f[x_, y_]] := Subscript[f, ToString[x] <> ToString[y]]

(m = Outer[(f @@ Sort[{##}])[t] &, labels, labels]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you recommend indexed versus not indexed? For some reason I thought we recommended against indexes with subscripts? Regardless, lovely code!!

Comment: @CATrevillian - subscripts/superscripts can case problems with some functions/commands. Rather than try to remember which ones, I always use indexed variables and format as desired.