# Understanding Function and Variable in Mathematica for beginner

Tags: functions, assignment

I'm reading the book of Leonid Shifrin, and I love the way the book explains the core in `Mathematica`. As everything is an expression, now I understand that, there are no real function or variable in `Mathematica`. Function is such an indexed variable containing several rules.

```
Head /@ {Sin, Sin[x], x, 3}
AtomQ /@ {Sin, Sin[x], x, 3}
Attributes /@ {Symbol, String, Integer}
```

> {Symbol, Sin, Symbol, Integer}
>
> {True, False, True, True}
>
> {{Locked, Protected}, {Protected}, {Protected}}

So both function `Sin` and variable `x` are `Symbol`. Everything in `Mathematica` is Symbol, String, or Number. This principle helps me a lot.

```
f = Sin;
g = Sin[x];
{f[x], g[x]}
```

> {Sin[x], Sin[x][x]}

Without this principle, a beginner can think that the function `g` equals to the function `Sin[x]`. So `g[x]` should return as `Sin[x]`. And he can think that the definition `f = Sin` is impossible because Sin should be expressed as a function Sin[something].

But here, we can see that `Mathematica` is very flexible. If we consider `Sin` as a variable, so assigning `f = Sin` is totally correct. And `g[x]` is not equal to `Sin[x]`, but `Sin[x][x]`. I think this is a very basic thing, that a beginner should remember.

So many books on `Mathematica` don't explain these principles, they just teach how to use the command. But understanding the core in Mathematica for me is much more important, because it is the basic to master `Mathematica` programming style. Thank you Leonid Shifrin.

As now, I see that functions and variable are `Symbol`. Beside `Symbol`, could we use another type as a variable?
For example, I would like to have a list of 40 variables a1=1, a2=2, a3=3,... a40=40. But I don't want to use indexed variable `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]`, `a[40]` because for me, it is just one variable `a` with several index.

Of course, the natural way is typing `a1 = 1`, `a2 = 2`, ... `a40 = 40` manually. But how to do it in automatically in a loop or table way?

My first try is to generate `"a1"`, `"a2"`, ... `"a40"` as `String`.

```
"a" <> # & /@ ToString /@ Table[i, {i, 3}]
```

> ```
> {"a1", "a2", "a3"}
> ```

But `String` can not be used as variable....

```
{"a1", "a2", "a3"} = {1, 2, 3}
```

> Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object a1. >>

So how to generate a list of variable? a1, a2, a3...?

I try to use `ToExpression` to convert the String to Expression, I got a list of variable a1,a2,a3.

```
ToExpression["a" <> # & /@ ToString /@ Table[i, {i, 3}]]
```

> {a1, a2, a3}

I'm trying to assign the value: (*)

```
ToExpression["a" <> # & /@ ToString /@ Table[i, {i, 3}]]] = {1, 2, 3}
```

> Set::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[{a1,a2,a3}] is Protected.
>
> > >

What is wrong here. I try to add Evaluate on the l.h.s:

```
Evaluate@ToExpression[
   "a" <> # & /@ ToString /@ Table[i, {i, 3}]] = {1, 2, 3}
{a1, a2, a3}
```

> {1, 2, 3}

Finally, it works. But are there any another way than this way (too long) to generate a list of variable `a1`, `a2`, `a40`? and why I need to `Evaluate` the l.h.s at (*) before `Set` to {1,2,3} ?

Edit: Thanks to @[RunnyKine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5709/runnykine), now I understand why I must `Evaluate` at (*) before using `Set`.

> "because when using Set, Mathematica evaluates the R.H.S. and leaves
>   the L.H.S. unevaluated."

Comment: Thanks for this, I really appreciate, and I am happy that the book works for you. Comments such as this show that writing the book was a good thing. But I see no question here. Our format on SE requires that one asks a question. Sorry, but we'll have to close this.

Comment: Although I agree with you that one of the biggest problems is that the core principles of *Mathematica* are not understood by even some long-term users, the problem of your article is, that it is no question. We all have agreed on how posts should look on StackExchange. What can we do with your post now, except of just closing it? Please review the [help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and make suggestions. Maybe you can edit your post and make it a real question?

Comment: Of courses, I have question. :)

Comment: Duplicate: [(6623)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6623/121).  Related: [(20758)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20758/121), [(20412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121), [(6511)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6511/121).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to know the things going on behind the scene, I first want you to think about the difference of `a[1], a[2], ...` and `a1, a2, ...`

For every value you set in either way, *Mathematica* creates a rule. In the first case, the rules are stored in the `DownValues` of `a`. In the latter they are stored in the `OwnValues` of `a1, a2, ..`.

```
{a[1], a[2], a[3]} = {1, 2, 3};
{a1, a2, a3} = {1, 2, 3};

DownValues[a]
OwnValues /@ Hold[a1, a2, a3] // ReleaseHold

(* 
  {HoldPattern[a[1]] :> 1, HoldPattern[a[2]] :> 2, HoldPattern[a[3]] :> 3}   
  Sequence[{HoldPattern[a1] :> 1}, {HoldPattern[a2] :> 2}, {HoldPattern[a3] :> 3}] 
*)
```

Therefore, it should not really have an impact on performance which version you choose. It is just that, as you have observed yourself, the first version with `a[1]` can be created more easily.

Nevertheless, there are ways to create a list `a1, a2, ...`. If you want new, unique variable-names, one of the easiest methods is using `Unique`. Here is a short snip creating a table and *showing* you what was set

```
Table[With[{var=Unique["a"],num=i},
  var=i;
  HoldForm[var=num]
  ],{i,1,10}]

(* {a15=1,a16=2,a17=3,a18=4,a19=5,a20=6,a21=7,a22=8,a23=9,a24=10} *)
```

A disadvantage of this method is that `Unique` really takes the next free variable. When you know for sure that your variables `a1, ..` don't have a value, you can use `Symbol` to create the symbol from a string

```
Table[Evaluate[Symbol["a" <> ToString[i]]] = i, {i, 1, 10}];
{a1,a2,a3}

(* {1, 2, 3} *)
```

Other things you should have a look at are `MakeExpression` and `ToExpression`.

Comment: You open my eyes ! Great ! I can use directly Symbol to generate a variable instead of using ToExpression. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While you may not like to use indexed variable, it is the most natural way to do what you want in *Mathematica*. But to satisfy your request, convert your created `String` to `Symbol`, then you can do the assignment.

```
Evaluate["a" <> # & /@ ToString /@ Table[i, {i, 3}] // Symbol /@ # &] = {1, 2, 3}
```

Note the use of `Evaluate` to force the L.H.S. to evaluate before making the assignment.

Comment: Could you please explain me, why we must Evaluate the l.h.s before making the assignment?

Comment: @DaoTRINH, because when using `Set`, *Mathematica* evaluates the R.H.S. and leaves the L.H.S. unevaluated.

Comment: Thank you very much @RunnyKine. This is another principle that I must remember. When using Set, the L.H.S unevaluated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that ToExpression is the function that you are looking for

```
In[9]:= ToExpression /@ Table["a" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, 10}]

Out[9]= {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}
```

in fact

```
In[11]:= Head /@ ToExpression /@ Table["a" <> ToString[i], {i, 1, 10}]

Out[11]= {Symbol, Symbol, Symbol, Symbol, Symbol, Symbol, Symbol, Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}
```