# How do we input powers of indexed variables?

Tags: symbolic, syntax, indexed-variable

I have tried

```
(a[i])^2
```

and alternatively

```
(a^2)[i]
```

Apparently both seem to work, but I was wondering what was the right way to do it?
This might sound like a silly question (apologies if it is). But I am doing some tedious calculations and I don't want a silly mistake to carry forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `a[i] = 2` compare what `(a[i])^2` evaluates versus what `(a^2)[i]` evaluates.

Comment: Short answer is the first. For explanation see this excellent [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127/34848). Also I suggest you read [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/34848).

Answer (score 2):

The universal answer for such kind of questions  is to compare `FullForm`s of the expessions. You will see their actual internal structure in a readable and (usually) easy-to-interpret form.

Recommended reading:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219/280
- [What are the requirements for a well behaved indexed variable? Subscript, ToExpression, Downvalue?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/280)
- http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39241/280
- [What is the distinction between DownValues, UpValues, SubValues, and OwnValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96/280)